# Filtering WADL documentation by package name at the time of building

Tags: java, rest, wadl

I am using jackson-jaxrs-1.5.7.jar for my rest web service. I am using Ant to generate resourcedoc.xml. Every thing is fine. But my problem is, In the web.xml I have added 4 resources (ie 4 package names- every one are different project) so that while hitting application.wadl from browser all the documentation for the packages that are mentioned in the web.xml are mapped. But I need the documentation for only one package. How to achieve it?? The CustomWADLGeneratorConfig is given below.

```
public class CustomWADLGeneratorConfig extends WadlGeneratorConfig{
@Override
public List<WadlGeneratorDescription> configure() {
    return generator(WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport.class).prop("resourceDocStream", "resourcedoc.xml").descriptions();
}
```